# How to make hiddenfor have value true

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My form has to set a Boolean to true but, the user wont' be able to interact with the control to change this.

I think the best approach is to use the `HiddenFor` as it's not desirable to set this in the Controller for various reasons but I can't set the Boolean to true...

My code

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(mod => mod.EmailAddress)<br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.EmailAddress)

                @Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.IsSubsribed, new { value = true })
            }
```

I've tried

```
      @Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.IsSubsribed, new { value = true })
      @Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.IsSubsribed, new { value = "true" })
      @Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.IsSubsribed, new { value = "checked" })
```

What do I need to do

Comment: If the user is not able to interact with the value, why include it in the view at all? Why not just hardcode it to `true` in the POST action of the controller?

Comment: Can't you initialize `IsSubsribed` to true inside model/controller? Whatever the value inside property that would be model bind to the control.

Comment: `"the user wont' be able to interact with the control to change this"` - Yes they will.  Easily.  If the user shouldn't be able to change the value then this shouldn't be on the page in the first place.  Keep server-side rules server-side.

Comment: @David, it's a hidden field! How does the user interact with it?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: Any user can send any data they want to your server.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions If it is an editable/selectable field then it make sense to model bind. But since you want to keep value in hidden field for tracking, either you can initialize value to `true` or use jQuery to set the value on document ready.

Comment: You set the value of `IsSubsribed = true` in the controller before you pass the mdoel to the view. Never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` method unless your wanting to screw up model binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

helper methods will ultimately render the input elements. So why not write an hidden input element tag ?

```
<input type="hidden" name="IsSubsribed" value="true" />
```

Or if you want to use the helper method, you can override the value explcititly (*Usually the helper method use the value of the expression (your property)*)

```
@Html.HiddenFor(d=>d.IsSubsribed,new { Value="true"})
```

**V** in `Value` **should be caps for this to work**

But remember, **user can still update this value and send it** . So do not rely on values coming from client. If you know this should be always true, use `true` in your http post action method(server code) instead of relying on this value coming from client browser

In short, **Do not blindly trust the data coming from client browser**. It can be easily altered

Comment: Does this mean it can't be done using `HiddenFor`? My question isn't about what I should do, it's more about how I could do it! And learning about the differences, not which way is best :)

Answer (score 0):

When calling: `@Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.IsSubsribed)`

If `IsSubsribed` is true, it will render:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IsSubsribed" value="true" />
```

If `IsSubsribed` is false, it will render:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IsSubsribed" value="false" />
```

If this is truly a parameter that cannot be modified by the user, a better convention is to use a hidden input that uniquely identifies the object being edited, and then perform sanity checks in the controller method given the primary key value.

**Model**

```
class MyModel
{
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PrimaryKey)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessModel(MyModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // lookup information based on model.PrimaryKey
        // process 'IsSubscribed...'
        // etc...

        // redirect to appropriate view
    }
    // invalid model state, return View for model
}
```